.net 8 Code execution stuck at CSharpCompilation.Emit() in docker
In our application we used following code to compile dynamic code. That code was working fine at .net 6
CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation
    .Create(
        "InMemoryAssembly",
        new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(stringText) },
        ReferenceAssemblies.Net80)
    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,  optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Debug, checkOverflow: true))
    .AddReferences(references);

try
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] byteAssembly = stream.ToArray();
        return (result, byteAssembly);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}

Now we upgraded our project at .net 8. Above code is working fine at windows but not in docker image.
At docker code execution get stuck at EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(stream); and it's does not throw any exception and no move on.
My docker file is
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
   $extraCommand
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY . .
   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]

Nuget packages I have used

Basic.Reference.Assemblies Version="1.6.0"
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp Version="4.10.0-2.final"
Microsoft.CSharp Version="4.7.0.0"
System.Reflection.Emit Version="4.7.0"

I don't understand why not throwing exception or move on.
Thanks for your help.
